# Is this sentence possible without ever, never, or before?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

A: He is a strange person. He doesn't say hello to anyone.

B: *I have seen the man like him.* He also doesn't say hello to anyone.

Can the sentence 'I have seen the man like him.'mean experiential usage without 'ever, never, or before in the present perfect sentence'?
I learned that experiential usage should have 'ever, never, or before in the sentence.
Please, tell me.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is yes, it can. Let me correct the sentence first:

> I have seen a man like him.

You don't want to use the definite article here, because you haven't *defined* a specific man that you are referring to.

It would be more correct to say that you *can* use *ever, never or before* with experiential usage, not that you *should*. These sentences have basically the same meaning as one another:

> Have you been to Delaware?
>   Have you ever been to Delaware?
>   Have you been to Delaware before?

As do these:

> Yes, I have been to Delaware.
>   Yes, I have been to Delaware before.

(We wouldn't say *Yes, I have ever been to Delaware*; in this case *ever* would be an archaic form of *always*.)

And these:

> No, I haven't been to Delaware.
>   No, I have never been to Delaware.
>   No, I haven't been to Delaware before.

There is a very slight difference in emphasis, but you would be fine using any of these.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **I have seen** can mean "I have seen or encountered at least once in my life".

In the question *Have you **ever** seen the northern lights?* the word **ever** means "at any time in your life".  If you reply *No, I have **never** seen the northern lights*, the word **never** means "at no time in my life".  You could reply, *Yes, I **have seen** the northern lights.*